# Using BeautifulSoup and lxml to extract nested divs in HTML code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have this HTML code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFSPT.jpg

I'm trying to extract and print the highlighted line in the image 
("some text").
"some text" is the text of the first div with `class=chat-message` nested in the div with `id=chat-messages` (In other words I'm trying to extract the text of the first child div of the div `id=chat-messages`, while all his children are similar in structure).
What I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "the url this is used for"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
g_data = soup.find('div',{'class':'chat-message-content selectable'})
print(g_data.text)
```

Which gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

As if `g_data` is `NULL`.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div data-reactroot="" id="app">
            <div class="top-bar-authenticated" id="top-bar">
            </div>


            <div class="closed" id="navigation-bar">
            </div>


            <div id="right-sidebar">
                <div id="chat">
                    <div id="chat-head">
                    </div>


                    <div id="chat-title">
                    </div>


                    <div id="chat-messages">
                        <div class="chat-message">
                            <div class="chat-message-avatar" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/657dcec97cc00bc378629930ecae1776c0d981e0.jpg&quot;);">
                            </div>
                            <a class="chat-message-username clickable">
                            <div class="iron-color">
                                aloe
                            </div></a>

                            <div class="chat-message-content selectable">
                                <!-- react-text: 2532 -->some text<!-- /react-text -->
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                            <div class="chat-message-avatar" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/657dcec97cc00bc378629930ecae1776c0d981e0.jpg&quot;);">
                            </div>
                            <a class="chat-message-username clickable">
                            <div class="iron-color">
                                aloe
                            </div></a>

                            <div class="chat-message-content selectable">
                                <!-- react-text: 2533 -->some other text<!-- /react-text -->
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>
```

Comment: @akashkarothiya How can I extract "some text" then?

Comment: Just tried on this URL : http://timsiteweb.free.fr/lxml.html and it worked ! Maybe the problem happens before, when you're making the request? What happens if you print `r.content`?

Comment: You're right, it's weird.. it prints (part of):  </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main">
  </div>

And not the content of the "main" div. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't know, I see one hypothesis: your HTML seems unfinished (it lacks of many `</div>` and `</body></html>`). Maybe try to complete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comments on the question I see you are trying to parse a website that loads the content using JavaScript, that's why `requests` is not working for you. You should use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) with a webdriver(e.g, [`Chromedriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads),[`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)). Something like the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.csgoarena.com/home")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
g_data = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'chat-message-content selectable'})
print(g_data)
```

Since you want the `.text` of all the selected elements:

```
>>> for match in g_data:
    print(match.text)


not everytime :D
I understand :)
 NuuZy csgoarena.com but he won GA's only when it were long 
Yea I always saw him
Everyday
caught
(...)
```

Comment: You've been so helpful. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for tags that match two or more CSS classes, you should use a CSS selector:

```
g_data = soup.select('div.chat-message-content.selectable')
```

Comment: Even though that works for the given html sample, the `lxml` parser supports multiple classes, so that's not the issue here.